# How can i make the users use the same table of the database with a different values?

Tags: asp.net

Please if someone have an idea about what i'm searching about.
i'm develloping an application web with asp.net and sql server. I have used a gridview and i want to make every new user after login see the gridview clear in order to create its own values.
But The gridview must still related with  the same table of the database.
I hope that you understand my problem and i'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the columns in the gird bound to columns of your users table or are they bound to it's own separate table?

If it's the latter, the table for the grid should have a column specifically for the users' id

for example, if the records for the gridview were held in table `USER_GRIDVIEW_RECORDS`:

```
ALTER TABLE USER_GRIDVIEW_RECORDS
    ADD USER_ID INT NOT NULL;
```

This way you can set the `DataSource` of the grid to the result of the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_GRIDVIEW_RECORDS
WHERE USER_ID = LOGED_IN_USER_ID
```

And write the records of the gridview back to the database with the following query.

```
INSERT INTO USER_GRIDVIEW_RECORDS (USER_ID, OTHER_COLUMN_NAMES, MORE_COLUMN_NAMES)
VALUES (LOGED_IN_USER_ID, 'Example value', 'another example')
```

If this isn't enough for you, give us some example code of how you query your server and about how you write the `DataSet` to the `DataSource` of your `GridView`